# Taskbar Icon is Not Persistent Between Folders

Tags: c#, windows

I created a C# application. In that application, I want to use a custom icon. I put the .ico file in the Icon and Manifest section in the Applications properties, as well as the Icon property for the form. When I run the exe from the Debug folder, the taskbar icon shows correctly. However, when I move the exe, the taskbar icon changes back to the default. What am I missing?

Update:

I tried to debug it a little and found it is just from a particular folder that I am running from that the icon does not stay. I ran it from the the Desktop, and the taskbar icon is correct. I ran it from a folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercury Suite\Etech Generator\EtechGenerator.exe --> does not work.

Desktop => Icon is right
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercury Suite\Etech Generator\EtechGenerator.exe => Icon is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system caches icons. Restart your computer to force it to refresh its cache.